# Как найти определенные числа

Tags: bash, awk

У меня есть файл, где указаны рандомно 100 чисел:

```
24 78 55 39 83 96 79 4 16 81 71 33 99 26 44 11 41 14 71 36 87 14 47 44 86 98 52 57 10 37 38 33 14 92 72 96 87 50 99 3 3
 70 36 30 95 79 40 36 92 11 71 78 24 17 22 9 14 74 66 24 10 3 57 23 95 28 18 82 77 17 84 7 86 19 36 81 97 76 17 88 86 8
 66 9 4 88 18 17 61 83 41 70 86 97 93 81 24 10 62 1
```

Мне из этого файла нужно вывести числа из первого десятка - [0-9]

Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью grep, но вывод некорректный:

grep {0..9} file

Comment: и как это можно осуществить с помощью awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -o '\<[0-9]\>' FILE
```

вариант с awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} $1>=0 && $1 <=9 {print $1}' FILE
```

или

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} /\<[0-9]\>/{print $1}' FILE
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло. подскажи, пожалуйста, что в данном случае делает ключ -o и для чего экранизация была <>

Comment: @bronix, ключ `-o, --only-matching       показывать только совпавшие непустые части строк`, а `\<` и `\>` это начало и конец слова соответственно.

Comment: спасибо большое) 
получается, что awk-скрипт выводит в командую строку значения, а как их отсортировать?
общий вывод должен быть таким:
0 - 9 : 8  где 0 - 9 это десяток, а 8 это числа которые входят в этот десяток из файла, где расположены 100 рандомных чисел

Comment: @bronix, не нужно делать марафон из разных вопросов в одной теме, тем более что вы уже задали его [в другой своей теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441205/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-awk-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82). И да, спасибо это хорошо, но лучше если использовать для этого предусмотренные инструменты на этом сайте, а именно  это отметка что ответ полезен и/или ответ отмечен как решением.