# распределение чисел через awk-скрипт

Tags: awk

У меня есть файл, где рандомно указано 100 чисел.

Файл имеет вид:

cat file

```
24
78
55
39
83
96
79
4
```

Мне нужно с помощью awk-скрипта вывести сколько чисел входит в каждый десяток, пример вывода:

0 - 9 : 9
10 - 19 : 5
20 - 29 : 2
и т.д. соответственно в первый десяток входит 9 чисел, во второй 5

как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то как это может сделать работу:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<10;i++) a[i]=0} {a[int($0/10)]++} END {for(i=0;i<10;i++) print a[i]}'
```

Идея в том, чтобы использовать массив и сделать левую цифру в качестве индекса.